# What is the additonal criteria to fullfill for Red Baron Hat?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

On [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com), I qualified for Red Baron Hat twice but never got it. From Winter Bash page:

> answer a question scoring -3 or lower; the question eventually becomes 3+ and your answer becomes 5+

And I completed it [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88949/why-arent-the-actual-people-involved-in-incidents-asked-to-do-reenactments) but no hat.

Is there any unsaid rule or some bug in calculations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your own votes do not count towards the total.

So if it was at -2, and you down voted it to -3, and posted an answer your answer would not be eligible.

If it was at -3, and your vote brought it up to +3, you will not get it unless it gets to +4.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

> answer a question scoring -3 or lower; the question eventually becomes 3+ and your answer becomes 5+

The *unsaid rule* is wait patiently after following the conditions exactly, your own votes can't be used to benefit you but other's actions can help or hurt you depending on hat type.

Here's your hat:

[image: Ankit's Red Baron Hat]

After waiting a day (in some cases) past due time (which is a week in some cases) it's fair to ask. Some things are calculated as they happen, or within a few minutes, others at the end of the day. Your question is an hour old, and now you have the hat.

Comment: Accepted answer already cover it and I got hat after this post.

Comment: Yes, you had to wait - which is what I said and what the accepted answer didn't say. I explained the *waiting criteria* and conditionals for other cases so when the same question is asked again ***this*** answer can serve as the duplicate.

Comment: I mean when I asked this post my criteria was not even meet as for new 3 score my upvote was considered too

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get this hat, because the question should be at 3+, which means it should have the score of more than 3.

Right now, the question score is 3.

[image]

Your answer is currently at 8 which is greater than 5, so your answer qualifies but the question doesn't which is why you didn't get the hat yet.

Comment: No, 3+ means "3 or higher".

Comment: @balpha Oh. +3 on the hat and 3+ in description. You managed to confuse me between pre and post increment. :P

Comment: That's why I maintain the opinion that using increments as an expression is always a bad idea 